# can yammer search Thai language

Tags: office365

I would like to know whether Yammer can search using Thai keyword.  I tried to search using Thai words but there is no result.  However, when I search using English keyword, Yammer gives me results.

Answer (score 0):

Update that was outdated information.

According to [Microsoft Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/languages.aspx) there are 50 Langauges supported including **Thai** have a look below.

> Microsoft Translator supports 50+ languages for text translation through the Microsoft Translator API. All of these languages are available in most products powered by Microsoft Translator including Translator for Bing, the Translator Web Widget, and Translator apps.
>
> Afrikaans Dutch   Hmong Daw   Lithuanian  Serbian (Cyrillic)  Vietnamese
>   Arabic  English Hungarian   Malay   Serbian (Latin) Welsh
>   Bosnian (Latin) Estonian    Indonesian  Maltese Slovak  Yucatec Maya
>   Bulgarian   Finnish Italian Norwegian   Slovenian
>   Catalan French  Japanese    Persian Spanish 
>   Chinese Simplified  German  Kiswahili   Polish  Swedish 
>   Chinese Traditional Greek   Klingon Portuguese  **Thai**
>   Croatian    Haitian Creole  Klingon (plqaD) Queretaro Otomi Turkish 
>   Czech   Hebrew  Korean  Romanian    Ukrainian
>   Danish  Hindi   Latvian Russian Urdu
>   Croatian    Haitian Creole  Klingon (plqaD) Queretaro Otomi Turkish 
>       Czech   Hebrew  Korean  Romanian    Ukrainian
>       Danish  Hindi   Latvian Russian Urdu

Comment: Maybe it is just a UI.  Yammer seems not to be able to search Thai contents.